# Selecting Cells Around a Selected ChartObject

Tags: vba, excel

I am totally new to VBA so sorry if this is a simple question. I have this problem at the moment: I have a worksheet with about 30 graphs in it. The problem is that the headers and sources at the bottom are in cells, not part of the graph. The company has accounted for this when formatting the "graph" region (there is a company wide standard format macro). I have tried the snippet below but as expected that only selects the actual graph regions. Is there a way to select the two rows above and below each of the graphs and iterate through that?

Thanks

```
Sub SelectAll()

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select

End Sub
```

Edit: This is what I'm currently working with, the chart in question is in Column T and Row 9 so going negative shouldn't be a worry.

```
   Sub SelectAll()

Worksheets("Real Estate").Activate
MsgBox ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").TopLeftCell.Address

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(.ChartObjects("Chart 1").TopLeftCell.Offset(-2, 0), _
            .ChartObjects("Chart 1").BottomLeftCell.Offset(4, 0)).Select
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the `TopLeftCell` and `BottomRightCell` of the chart object and `OFFSET` from those cells.

For example:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").BottomRightCell
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").TopLeftCell
```

These two cells can then be used to return the range surrounding the chart:

```
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.ChartObjects("Chart 1").TopLeftCell.Offset(-2, -2), _
            .ChartObjects("Chart 1").BottomRightCell.Offset(2, 2)).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't quite seem to get it working, this makes logical sense to me but I keep getting 'Object doesn't support this property or method' 
I assume I just am not putting in my slightly different names for things correctly. My sheet is named "Real Estate" and the chart is "Chart 1"

Comment: I fixed the earlier issue, although now I'm getting Method 'Offset' of object 'Range' failed.

Comment: @ChrisNovak - Sorry, wasn't getting notifications that you'd replied, add my name with the @ so I get a notification to any comments.  To find the chart name select the chart and look on the _Layout_ ribbon under _Properties_.  If your chart is in column A or B, or in rows 1 or 2 you'll get problems as you can't offset by -2 cells which would take you off the sheet.  Could you edit your question with your full code please - I get an `Application-defined or object-defined error` when trying to offset off the sheet, so not sure how you're coding it.

Comment: @DarrenBartrupCook Apologies, must've not done that @ correctly before

Comment: No problem - shouldn't have to do it if you commenting on my post, so not sure what happened.  Your code says `BottomLeftCell` it should be `BottomRightCell`.

Comment: I changed that, same error code though "Method 'Offset' of object 'Range' failed

Comment: I'm not sure then - your `SelectAll` code works fine for me as long as I use `.Range(.ChartObjects("Chart 1").TopLeftCell.Offset(-2, 0), ("Chart 1").BottomRightCell.Offset(4, 0)).Select` and have the chart below row 2.  Does the message box return an address?  If you change `BottomRightCell` to `TopLeftCell` does it select a range - the wrong range, but a range?